# Unable to RefunSale sale in PayPal using PHP SDk (undefined getApiContext)

Tags: php, laravel, paypal

I am trying to refund sale in PayPal using PHP SDK. However, it is showing error as 
`Call to undefined function App\Http\Payment\PayPal\getApiContext()` I am trting to refund using PHP SDk of paypal.

```
use PayPal\Api\Amount;
use PayPal\Api\RefundRequest;
use PayPal\Api\Sale;


        $amt = new Amount();
        $amt->setTotal($amount)
            ->setCurrency('USD');

        // ### Refund object
        $refundRequest = new RefundRequest();
        $refundRequest->setAmount($amt);


        // ###Sale
        $sale = new Sale();
        $sale->setId($sale_id);
        try {
            // Create a new apiContext object so we send a new
            // PayPal-Request-Id (idempotency) header for this resource
            $apiContext = getApiContext(config('paypal.id'), config('paypal.secret'));
            // Refund the sale
            // (See bootstrap.php for more on `ApiContext`)
            $refundedSale = $sale->refundSale($refundRequest, $apiContext);
        } catch (\Exception $ex) {
            echo $ex;
            exit(1);
        }

        return $refundedSale;
```

### update:

I am referring  https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/blob/master/sample/sale/RefundSale.php

Comment: Which line is the error occurring on? What have you tried?

Comment: `$apiContext = getApiContext(config('paypal.id'), config('paypal.secret'))` this line it is referring that `getApiContext` function could not be found